# Unable to access to elasticsearch nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, quorum

I have an elastic cluster with 3 nodes which are located into 2 machines. Unfortunately the machine which has 2 of the 3 nodes has crashed and I can't access to its data. And now I just have one node that can't start its job. Its output shows the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot start with [discovery.type] set to [single-node] when local node {elastics01}{f4PtBIkPSACZ_uEht1PnOA}{HtLbgM13RxWZuWMP19DIUA}{192.168.132.40}{192.168.132.40:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=6246580224, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=512, ml.max_jvm_size=536870912} does not have quorum in voting configuration VotingConfiguration{z8C2zvqXQUu5bMwkmi9Wdw,f4PtBIkPSACZ_uEht1PnOA,kopBE3hDQAudaAbWU8lsEA}

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

if you are running 7.X, and unless you have a snapshot (a backup), then you are out of luck because you have lost quorum

from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-quorums.html;

> To be sure that the cluster remains available you **must not stop half or more of the nodes in the voting configuration at the same time**. As long as more than half of the voting nodes are available the cluster can still work normally. This means that if there are three or four master-eligible nodes, the cluster can tolerate one of them being unavailable. If there are two or fewer master-eligible nodes, they must all remain available.

this is likely very frustrating, however this is how Elasticsearch works with it's distributed model, which is why it's explicitly called out in the docs

Comment: It seems I need 3 separate machines for the three nodes to stop the problem happen again